# Magento 2 : How to add new fields in eav_attribute?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

For my custom modules I need some new fields for product attributes in eav_attribute. Does anyone know how to add these fields?

Comment: Use product attribute and the values will be saved in type specific table like eav_entity_varchar etc..,

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in: `Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php`

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
       $eavSetup->addAttribute(
               \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
           'attribute_code',
           [
               'group' => 'General',
               'type' => 'int',
               'label' => 'attribute_label',
               'backend' => '',
               'input' => 'select',
               'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
               'source' => 'Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\YesNo',
               'required' => true,
               'sort_order' => 15,
               'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav
                           \Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
               'used_in_product_listing' => false,
               'visible_on_front' => false,
       ]
   );

   $setup->endSetup();
```

Source file mentioned above so by defaulty value will be set

```
class YesNo extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    protected $_options;

    /**
     * getAllOptions
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if ($this->_options === null) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['value' => '0', 'label' => __('No')],
                ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Yes')]
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
    final public function toOptionArray()
    {
       return array(
        array('value' => '0', 'label' => __('No')),
        array('value' => '1', 'label' => __('Yes'))
    );
   }
}
```

Use Below Cose in: `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="Your_attribute_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your_Label</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>s
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I dont need new attributes, I need to add new table fields in the table eav_attribute.

Comment: Ups, I understand now, instead of adding in the table eav_attribute, I add the required table fields as attributes, right?

Comment: yes you need to create attribute